# Nested JSON Object (Retrofit)

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit

I'm using Retrofit to send picture request and receive this Json

```
{"response":{
    "face":{
        "value":"true",
        "confidence":55
    },
    "gender":{
        "value":"male",
        "confidence":73
    },
    ...
}}
```

and I'm receiving it with **Retrofit**....

```
   RestAdapter adapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                    .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
                    .setEndpoint(END_POINT)
                    .build();
   Mylistenerr listener = adapter.create(Mylistenerr.class);
   File photo = new File(picturePath);
   TypedFile image = new TypedFile("multipart/image/jpg", photo);
   listener.setUserImage(
       image,
       new Callback<respostring>() {
           @Override
           public void success(respostring rp, Response arg1) {}

          @Override
          public void failure(RetrofitError arg0) {
             pd.hide();
             pd.dismiss();
             Log.d("ERROR:", arg0.getLocalizedMessage());
          }
      });     
    }

    private static class respostring {
       private Content face;
       private Content gender;
           respostring() {}
    }


   class Content
   { 
      private int confidence;
      private String value;

      Content(){}

      public int getconf(){
        return this.confidence;
      }
      public String getvalue(){
        return this.value;
      }
}
```

My interface

```
public interface Mylistenerr {
  @Multipart
  @POST("/public/test")
  void setUserImage(
     @Part("image") TypedFile file,          
     Callback<respostring> response);
}
```

but there is retrofit error. Is there something I miss here?

Comment: waht is "respostring" in Callback<respostring> response); ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend you using Gson for json deserialization instead since retrofit supports it very well. Then you can just create classes like this:

Your face class:

```
public class Face implements Serializable {

    @SerializedName("value")
    public boolean value;

    @SerializedName("confidence")
    public int confidence;

}
```

Your gender class:

```
public class Gender implements Serializable {

    @SerializedName("value")
    public String value;

    @SerializedName("confidence")
    public int confidence;

}
```

your response class:

```
public class YourResponseType implements Serializable {

    @SerializedName("face")
    public Face face;

    @SerializedName("gender")
    public Gender gender;
}
```

Then you can actually make retrofit doing the rest for you:

```
listener.setUserImage(image, new Callback<YourResonseType>() {...});
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: oh sorry I forgot to add a class that wraps the response. Would be something like public class MyResponseContainer implements Serializable { @SerializedName("response") YourResponseType yourResponse; }

Comment: yes it is missing  i discovered that later and i was gonna come to write it ... but you did find it ,, thank you a lot  :)